# non AngularJS way of reading $localstorage

Tags: javascript, angularjs, cookies, ng-storage

So normally I would use `cookies` to parse data from one `AngularJS` application to another, and then read those cookies before `bootstrapping` my application.

The problem with this approach is that the cookies have a size limit. And to get around this I thought about using `$localstorage` from the `ngStorage` library.

Now my problem is, how do I read the data stored in my `$localstorage` before `bootstrapping` my application, ie: in pure `JavaScript`?

Comment: `localStorage.getItem('Key')`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is really simple:

**Store item:**

```
localStorage.setItem('key', 'value');
```

**Get Item:**

```
localStorage.getItem('key');
```

You may want to store JSON in the storage, so you can always use **JSON.stringify(var)** in your set method, and **JSON.parse(var)** after your get.